# Sequelize with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm following a [tutorial](http://redotheweb.com/2013/02/20/sequelize-the-javascript-orm-in-practice.html) which uses sequelize with an express project. Here's the `user.js` model:

```
// in models/User.js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('User', {
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    instanceMethods: {
      countTasks: function() {
        // how to implement this method ?
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Then he uses `User` in various of ways, for example:

```
var user = User.build({ first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe' });
```

I understand the code in general, but I don't understand completely why `module.exports` gets a function with two parameters (sequelize, DataTypes). I haven't seen it initialized anywhere in the code. How is it working then?

Comment: Sequelize initializes it internally, you have nothing to do with it in your code, as far as I understand. It's same pattern used in any url, when you give ORM function to describe your model, and ORM does the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are following [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20141205221135/http://sequelizejs.com/articles/express) you will see in `models/index.js` that all model definitions are looped through and passed to `seqelize.import()`.

You will find that [this line of code](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/2.0/lib/sequelize.js#L627) within `sequelize.import` calls the model's module function and passes a reference to `sequelize` and `DataTypes` to the model.

In the tutorial you referenced, the author uses a similar method within `models/index.js`

#### > Edit (7/14/2015)

**Since the link does not work and I could not find it on their current site, I copied the code from their site using [The Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/). I also updated the second link to point to the 2.0 docs instead of master.**

**models/index.js**

```
"use strict";

var fs        = require("fs");
var path      = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
var db        = {};

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
```

Comment: Link to the guide is broken.